# Проблемы с пагинацией

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

Никак не могу прикрутить пагинацию к этой странице: [страница скидок](http://www.staff-demo.pp.ua/skidki/).

Использую woocommerce вместе с темой: [savoy.nordicmade.com](http://savoy.nordicmade.com/)

Скидки вывожу шордкодом:

```
[sale_products per_page="8" pagination="true"]
```

Поставил еще плагин «Shortcode Pagination for WooCommerce»… На странице категории (из коробки темы) все работает, на странице скидок — нет (
подключил уже необходимые скрипты, но все равно не работает)…

Что я еще упустил?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по актуальному коду, выводящему шорткоды WooCommerce, в файле `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/shortcodes/class-wc-shortcode-products.php`, атрибут `per_page` устарел и заменен на `limit`. Атрибут `pagination` не существует и, насколько мне известно, никогда не существовал.

Пагинация в выводе шорткодом не предусмотрена. Атрибут `limit` ограничивает общее количество выводимых товаров, но не создает пагинацию. Об этом же написано в [документации](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/).

Это и понятно - у вас на сайте может быть в блоге, скажем, много записей, будет работать пагинация блога, а в записях может присутствовать шорткод WooCommerce. И как тогда разруливать две пагинации?

**Резюме такое**. Пагинацию через стандартный шорткод сделать нельзя. Надо создавать свой цикл по продуктам через WP_Query и прикручивать к нему свою пагинацию.

Плагин Shortcode Pagination for WooCommerce прокомментировать не могу, не работал с ним.